# Firebase Functions error after updating to node 10

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hi my firebase functions error after updating to node 10

Here is the error log:

```
Process exited with code 16
    at process.on.code (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:393:29)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
    at logAndSendError (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:184:9)
    at process.on.err (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:390:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:119:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)
```

I cannot figure out anything from these logs and there is nothing popping up on google when I search about this.

My code has not changed and this happens with most of my functions.

Comment: seen this happen at random once or twice with my functions too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you answered your own question about a month later over at your very similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57164178/708998

Just thought I'd update this for all those who stumble their way there via google like I did.