# Firebase cloud function exits with code 16 what is error code 16 and where can I find more info?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

one of my cloud functions on firebase exits with code 16 as an error.

I tried to google and find out what that code is but no luck at all.

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.on.code (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:393:29)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
    at logAndSendError (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:184:9)
    at process.on.err (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:390:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:119:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)
```

Where can I find those error codes reported so I can understand why my function exits?

Comment: If you're having problems with the Firebase CLI emulator, post an issue on its GitHub.  Stack Overflow is probably not going to be very useful to you.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson thanks for the reply. I am not having any issue with the emulator. this is production issue and I am looking into learning where I can find those exit codes for node I suppose.

Comment: Then you'll want to provide a MCVE with your post, so that anyone can reproduce the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: did you update nodeJs/npm recently? I also get a similar issue but forget it now. after downgrading it worked

Comment: @DougStevenson why do I need an example? I just want to know what that error code for node means or where to look up those codes... I am not asking to solve my error.

Comment: You might be doing something obviously wrong in your code, in which case, someone might be able to point it out.  It's up to you, but I doubt you'll get much helpful feedback without a code sample and a description of what it's trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think I am on it. Must be that I am sending headers of `500` and then later on the function continues to run and sends another header. But that was my case. 
I would have found this out, if I knew for example that code 16 is perhaps `Headers already sent`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code for the function framework is actually public in the [GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/blob/240defc0a6c7076fcffef89bdf6b95a0a1f95f48/src/invoker.ts) repository (although not advertised anywhere).

In particular you can see there the cases where `killInstance` is used, which is the one triggering exit code 16:

`const killInstance = process.exit.bind(process, 16);`

These cases are (at the time of writing):

- [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)
- [unhandledRejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection)

Comment: Are you sure these are the 2 options only? And not having already sent the headers? 

If yes I need to mark this as correct and not my answer.

Comment: yes, this is the only place where exit(16) is called. That being said it could be possible that duplicate headers trigger an exception, which could appear in an un-catched async block of your function, hence triggering unhandledRejection, hence triggering this behavior, but the first hint/answer shouldn't be this one (it wasn't in my case)

Comment: Let me mark yours as valid, because its more complete , and holds this info. 

Thank. you

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. I encountered this error when I forgot to write `await` in a try-catch block so there was an uncaught rejection.

Answer (score 24):

Apparently and after investigation, the error means something like: `Headers already sent`.

I had somewhere in my code a `response.send()` with headers and then, later on, I was sending another response.

Would be great if the Firebase team could elaborate with these issues and provide some documentation instead of leaving us blindfolded (to my understanding)

Comment: I got hit by this today (again, forgot a return after an error). Where did you find the error codes? Did you report it to the Firebase team?

Comment: @Leo check the cloud console (google) that posts the codes there

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the explanation of for example code 16. I only saw something like what you posted on the question.

Answer (score 14):

An improperly terminated cloud function is the likely cause.

Here's what the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) say:

- Resolve functions that perform asynchronous processing (also known as
  "background functions") by returning a JavaScript promise.
- Terminate HTTP functions with `res.redirect()`, `res.send()`, or
  `res.end()`.
- Terminate a synchronous function with a `return`; statement.

In short, watch out for [floating promises](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-floating-promises/) and/or multiple calls to `res` or `response`.

I've also seen the `Process exited with code 16` occur in tandem with:

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/srv/functions/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:161:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. As @cDitch mentions my code was not 100% complete. However the biggest issue for me were **outdated packages**.

I needed to upgrade firebase-admin, firebase-functions and firebase-tools as well as eslint.

you can see which packages are outdated by running:

```
npm outdated
```

Then i've changed the dependencies manually inside the package.json to the latest version mentioned by npm outdated.

It's possible that it'll cause deploy issues after you do this. At least this is what happened to me. Completely removing the node_modules and reinstalling them fixed this.

Here's two lines i've added to my package.json scripts to do this on windows:

```
"clean": "rmdir /s /q node_modules",
"reinstall": "npm run clean && npm install",
```

- rmdir -> delete a directory
- /s -> delete the whole tree (so all
  folder within)
- /q -> do this quietly so you dont flood your terminal and have to wait all printed lines.

now you can run the following command

```
npm run clean
npm install
```

or

```
npm run reinstall
```

to execute those steps.