# Code 16 when uploading file to storage from Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to put `JSON` data in a blob and then upload it as a `.json` file into my cloud storage. 
I have initialized the storage as `var storage = admin.storage()` in earlier code, my function is trying to get date which is then formatted to reflect name of the `JSON` object from previous day, retrieves it from realtime `DB` and then stringifies it, everything works to this point as I've been logging data along the way, however once I try to upload the blob I'm getting below error:

> Error: Process exited with code 16
>           at process.on.code (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:396:29)
>           at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
>           at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
>           at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
>           at logAndSendError (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:184:9)
>           at process.on.err (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:389:13)
>           at process.emit (events.js:203:15)
>           at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
>           at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:497:27)

Here is my code:

```js
exports.archiveLogs = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every day 01:01")
  .onRun((context) => {
    //get previous date in correct format (to reference collection name)
    var rightNow = new Date();
    var dateOffset = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1; //1 days
    rightNow.setTime(rightNow.getTime() - dateOffset);
    //to formatted string
    var day = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, "");
    console.log("Running archive logs with date: ", day);
    var ref = logDB.ref(`logs/${day}`);
    //retrieve data from realtime db
    ref.on(
      "value",
      function (snapshot) {
        //stringy retrieved data and put it in a blob
        var dataString = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val());
        var blob = new Blob([dataString], {
          type: "application/json",
        });
        //reference to location where the file will be saved
        var storageRef = storage.ref().child(`/logs/${day}.json`);
        storageRef
          .put(blob)
          .then((snapshot) => {
            console.log("Uploaded a blob!");
            logUserActivity(
              "system",
              "system",
              "archive_logs",
              "Pass",
              `Created JSON: ${day}.json at /logs/`
            );
            return true;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error uploading to storage.", err);
          });
      },
      function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: I would recommend you to check possible causes, as per this other case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149416/firebase-cloud-function-exits-with-code-16-what-is-error-code-16-and-where-can-i), to verify if the behavior is the same that you are facing. In case it's not, could you please confirm if withou using `blob`, you are able to upload to Cloud Storage?