# Error code 16 and Error code 14, With a Schedule Cloud Function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am getting these two errors with my scheduled cloud function, the functions runs fine but in my logs I am getting these:

```
Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:175:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:341:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:304:181)
at Http2CallStream.outputStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:116:74)
at Http2CallStream.maybeOutputStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:155:22)
at Http2CallStream.endCall (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:141:18)
at Http2CallStream.cancelWithStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:457:14)
at ChannelImplementation.tryPick (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js:237:32)
at Object.updateState (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/channel.js:106:26)
```

And this one:

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
at process.on.code (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:396:29)
at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
at logAndSendError (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:184:9)
at process.on.err (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:393:13)
at process.emit (events.js:198:13)
at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:140:18)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)
```

This is my code:
I am running the function for test purposes every 5 minutes, it will run every day of the month once.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

/// Checks every day if the debt pay day is equal to the setting and add the corresponding amount to 
/// the debt
export const checkForMonthChange = functions.pubsub
  .schedule("every 5 minutes")
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    const configData = await admin
      .firestore()
      .doc("neighbors/0000_admin")
      .get();
    const dayToPay = configData.data()?.day_of_month_to_pay;
    console.log(`Day to Pay: ${dayToPay}`);
    const dayOfMonth = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
      .toDate()
      .toString()
      .substr(8, 2);
    console.log(`Current Day of Month: ${dayOfMonth}`);

    if (dayOfMonth === dayToPay) {
      return admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("neighbors")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            return doc.ref.update({
              debt: doc.data()?.debt + configData?.data()?.monthly_pay,
            });
          });
        });
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Could you please check if these other two cases - [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/568) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149416/firebase-cloud-function-exits-with-code-16-what-is-error-code-16-and-where-can-i) - help you with finding and fixing the errors? In case they don't, more information regarding your environment and how, when, the functions is run will be needed in an update in the question.

Comment: Hi Gabriel thanks for the answer i have checked both links in the first one they suggest to update to  
"firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
 "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0" , and I have     "firebase-admin": "^8.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.7.0"
the other one suggest to end the function with a return, I think i am doing that or maybe I am missing something or making a mistake somewhere in my code, what other information I can provide and how do I get it?

Comment: HI @MiguelChave I would recommend you to reach out to Firebase 1:1 support. Due to the fact that this seems to be a different issue from the similar ones, further troubleshooting and analysis will be needed on Firebase's side. You can contact them [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact).

Comment: Will do thanks Gabriel