# Firebase Cloud Function Error: Process exited with code 16

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am getting this two errors in my Firebase console.

It seems it does not execute the Restart() function of my cloud function anymore.

I will post my cloud function below.

Until now I did not find a solution for this error.

Does someone know what could be the issue?

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:275:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:167:15)
    at Object.sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:37:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:271:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)

Error: set
    at Repo.abortTransactionsOnNode_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14740:67)
    at Repo.abortTransactions_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14701:10)
    at Repo.setWithPriority (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12685:33)
    at Reference.set (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:13775:19)
    at /workspace/bot2.js:39:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

And this is my function:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
//admin.initializeApp();

exports.bot2 = functions.database.ref('/users/-BOT2QMlrb5yV1D5R-rP/health')
    .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
        const before = change.before.val();  // DataSnapshot before the change
        const after = change.after.val();  // DataSnapshot after the change
        console.log('health = ', after);

        if (before === after) {
            console.log("Health didn't change");
            return null;
        }

        var clicker = (await admin.database().ref('/users/-BOT2QMlrb5yV1D5R-rP/clickedby/').once('value')).val();

        admin.database()
            .ref('/users/-BOT2QMlrb5yV1D5R-rP/clickedby/')
            .on('value', function (snapshot) {
                clicker = snapshot.val();
            });

        console.log('clicker = ', clicker);

        var clickerclickedby = admin.database().ref('/users/' + clicker + '/clickedby');
        var clickerhealth = admin.database().ref('/users/' + clicker + '/health');
        var clickerscore = admin.database().ref('/users/' + clicker + '/score');

        if (after > 0 && after < 10) {
            clickerhealth.transaction(count => count - 1);
            clickerclickedby.set('-BOT2QMlrb5yV1D5R-rP');
        }

        if (after <= 0) {
            clickerscore.transaction(count => count + 1);
            clickerhealth.set(10);
            change.after.ref.parent.child('score').set(0);
            //setTimeout(() => change.after.ref.parent.child('health').set(10),3000);
            setTimeout(Restart, 3000, change.after.ref.parent);
        }
        return null;
    })

function Restart(ref) {
    ref.child('score').set(0);
    ref.child('health').set(10);
}
```

Here are the logs I have downloaded from Logs Explorer:

```
[
  {
    "textPayload": "Error: set\n    at Repo.rerunTransactionQueue_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14589:67)\n    at Repo.rerunTransactions_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14494:10)\n    at /workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14473:19\n    at /workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11900:17\n    at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11930:17)\n    at Connection.onDataMessage_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11247:14)\n    at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11241:18)\n    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11142:27)\n    at WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10728:18)\n    at WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10779:22)",
    "insertId": "000000-2ce372c8-9948-4e76-98a1-ceb56f596e86",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "function_name": "bot2",
        "region": "us-central1",
        "project_id": "battle-click"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-01-17T13:01:22.948Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "execution_id": "ekcpygd17zks"
    },
    "logName": "projects/battle-click/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/battle-click/traces/044ed44b50a138d4de4a95383a11c935",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-17T13:01:27.347188676Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Error: Process exited with code 16\n    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:275:22)\n    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:167:15)\n    at Object.sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:37:9)\n    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:271:22)\n    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)",
    "insertId": "000000-7c13e8b3-0595-41e4-901c-4a6e2643994d",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "function_name": "bot2",
        "project_id": "battle-click",
        "region": "us-central1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-01-17T13:01:24.044Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "execution_id": "ekcpygd17zks"
    },
    "logName": "projects/battle-click/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/battle-click/traces/044ed44b50a138d4de4a95383a11c935",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-17T13:01:27.347188676Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging Request rejected.\n",
    "insertId": "000000-162167fa-fc24-4f1e-96a1-1595b973136b",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "battle-click",
        "function_name": "bot2",
        "region": "us-central1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-01-18T11:00:21.419911849Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "execution_id": ""
    },
    "logName": "projects/battle-click/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-18T11:00:21.760209675Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Error: set\n    at Repo.abortTransactionsOnNode_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14740:67)\n    at Repo.abortTransactions_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14701:10)\n    at Repo.setWithPriority (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:12685:33)\n    at Reference.set (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:13775:19)\n    at /workspace/bot2.js:39:27\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)",
    "insertId": "000000-0efc4e49-5776-4aea-938f-385f2340f032",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "battle-click",
        "function_name": "bot2",
        "region": "us-central1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-01-23T21:57:15.830Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "execution_id": "4cifdb3v583i"
    },
    "logName": "projects/battle-click/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/battle-click/traces/50790baa80493a267baf9024017d515a",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-23T21:57:18.243185578Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Error: Process exited with code 16\n    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:275:22)\n    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:167:15)\n    at Object.sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:37:9)\n    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:271:22)\n    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)",
    "insertId": "000000-c3fd188b-c84f-4782-904f-e4ba42cc8c09",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "region": "us-central1",
        "project_id": "battle-click",
        "function_name": "bot2"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-01-23T21:57:16.866Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "execution_id": "4cifdb3v583i"
    },
    "logName": "projects/battle-click/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/battle-click/traces/50790baa80493a267baf9024017d515a",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2021-01-23T21:57:18.243185578Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Error: set\n    at Repo.rerunTransactionQueue_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14589:67)\n    at Repo.rerunTransactions_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14494:10)\n    at /workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:14473:19\n    at /workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11900:17\n    at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11930:17)\n    at Connection.onDataMessage_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11247:14)\n    at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11241:18)\n    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:11142:27)\n    at WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10728:18)\n    at WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:10779:22)",
    "insertId": "000000-290c28fe-9f30-4ce0-9d77-fae0fbfed43a",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "region": "us-central1",
        "function_name": "bot2",
        "project_id": "battle-click"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-02-04T07:33:49.281Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "execution_id": "z94j8k8kfqb5"
    },
    "logName": "projects/battle-click/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/battle-click/traces/495c84c3eef023d6bff49d8060a5da7c",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2021-02-04T07:33:52.269491250Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Error: Process exited with code 16\n    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:275:22)\n    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:167:15)\n    at Object.sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:37:9)\n    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:271:22)\n    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)",
    "insertId": "000000-e47d8b65-987c-4ce3-86a9-4b98b4ab966e",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "labels": {
        "function_name": "bot2",
        "region": "us-central1",
        "project_id": "battle-click"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2021-02-04T07:33:50.295Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "labels": {
      "execution_id": "z94j8k8kfqb5"
    },
    "logName": "projects/battle-click/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
    "trace": "projects/battle-click/traces/495c84c3eef023d6bff49d8060a5da7c",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2021-02-04T07:33:52.269491250Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello, while looking at the error 16 in GCF, I could find that this is a standard way to end the functions when it finds a uncaughtException or a unhandledRejection, see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149416/firebase-cloud-function-exits-with-code-16-what-is-error-code-16-and-where-can-i) I would suggest to look into the Cloud Function logs (stackdriver logs) to find why is the function terminated that way.

Comment: Thank you Luis. I have downloaded the logs from Logs Explorer and added them to my question. But I dont understand what causes the errors and how I can catch them.

Comment: Hello, While investigating the issue, I tried to go to the base [code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/database/src/core/Repo.ts) of the errors and I found the next comment under  repoAbortTransactionsOnNode (and the error does references a set in your code on line 39): " * Aborts all transactions on ancestors or descendants of the specified path.
 * Called when doing a set() or update() since we consider them incompatible
 * with transactions." ****. I think this may be useful for this issue.

Comment: Thank you Luis. The following are the lines 38 and 39 in my function:
38. clickerscore.transaction(count => count + 1);
39. clickerhealth.set(10);
Could it be that the clickerhealth path is not valid anymore because the clicker has already left the game and than there is no more entry in the database? Until now I was not able to reproduce the error by myself.