# Firebase functions with nodemailer POST request: Error: Process exited with code 16

Tags: firebase, express, nodemailer

I'm running a Firebase cloud function whose purpose is to handle the backend of a "contact me" form. The Express framework is being used for middleware functions. When the submit button is clicked, a `POST` request is made to the `/submit` endpoint.

`index.js` in the functions folder is as below:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const emailRoute = require("./routes/email");

// Initialize Firebase in order to access its services.
admin.initializeApp();

const app = express();

// Automatically allow cross-origin requests.
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(emailRoute);

// Expose Express API as a single Cloud Function.
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The imported router from `email.js` is as follows:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
  
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "email@gmail.com",
      pass: "password",
    },
  });

  const myEmail = {
    to: "myemail@gmail.com",
    subject: `A new message from ${req.body.name}`,
    text: `${req.body.name} sent the following message:
          \n\n ${req.body.message}
          \n\n Senders email: ${req.body.email}`,
  };

  const sendersEmail = {
    to: req.body.email,
    subject: "A copy of your message to me",
    text: `You just sent me the following message:\n\n${req.body.message}`,
  };

  console.log("SUBMIT REQUEST PROCESSING");

  transporter.sendMail(myEmail);
  transporter.sendMail(sendersEmail);

  res.redirect("/#contact");

  console.log("PROCESSING COMPLETE");
});

module.exports = router;
```

There is no issue when running this in the local environment - the email gets sent to both parties. However, when run in the hosted environment as a Firebase function the following error is thrown: `Error: Process exited with code 16` (as displayed in the function logs section of the Firebase console). A previous SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149416/firebase-cloud-function-exits-with-code-16-what-is-error-code-16-and-where-can-i) indicates an `uncaughtException` or `unhandledRejection`.

Before the error, both `console.log()` statements are logged. Then the function finishes with a `302` status code (as it does when run locally and successfully). After that, there is the unhandled rejection followed by `Error: Invalid login` and a link to my Google account and a statement "Please log in via your web browser and then try again".

Could this be a Firebase security measure against automated mailing that `nodemailer` is attempting to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to both enable [less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) and [display unlock captcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) on the gmail account, only the former of which I had previously done.

I also needed to set the `gmail.email` and `gmail.password` Google cloud environment variables. This can be done with the following shell command: `firebase functions:config:set gmail.email="myusername@gmail.com" gmail.password="secretpassword"`

A great resource I found on this is an [official Firebase function sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users) that utilises Nodemailer, where the above is covered.

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important information in the link provided in the answer itself. This can help prevent your answer from becoming invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.

Comment: The three pertinent points have already been listed, the Firebase function sample doesn't go into much more detail there. Having said that, it does provide a link for the first 2 points and provides a shell command for the third. I'll edit to include all that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in logging to your Google account. Have you enabled less secure apps in your Google account? Or better I would recommend to use some other authentication, as described here:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: Yes I've enabled less secure apps. In fact, I've got it working when hosted remotely on Namecheap as an Express server. The problem occurs when I move hosting to Firebase and have to use their serverless environment via Firebase functions.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion to use a SMTP relay service, that requires an admin account with Google Workspace. They are all paid plans unfortunately - I'm just using this for a personal project so can't really justify that expense.