# Error: Process exited with code 16 google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

this function is used to send FCM to multiple users whose FCM tokens and notification data is read from FIRESTORE storage. it reads data from firestore storage then it checks for the time of the notification if is verified it sends the push notification to that devices fcm token.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


 var db = admin.firestore();

exports.notification = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    
  let token;
  var notif;
  let time ;
  var current = new Date();
  const citiesRef = db.collection('notifications');
const snapshot = await citiesRef.where('token', '!=', "").get();

   if (snapshot.empty) {
    console.log('No matching documents.');
    return;
  }else{
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.get('token'));
    token = doc.get('token');
    notif = doc.get('notif');
    time = doc.get('data');

           console.log('list size',time.length);

           if(notif ==1){
           var index, len;
           for (index = 0, len = time.length; index < len; ++index) {

                  var d = new Date(time[index].date);
                  var h_notif = d.getHours();
                  var m_notif = d.getMinutes();
                  var h_curr = current.getHours();
                  var m_curr = current.getMinutes();

                      if(h_curr-h_notif ===0){
                    
                          console.log('after hour check',time[index].title,'===>',time[index].body);
                          console.log(m_notif,'==>',m_curr);
                          if(m_curr-m_notif <5 && m_curr-m_notif >= 0){
                    
                            const payload = {
                            data: {
                              title:time[index].title ,
                              body:time[index].body,
                            }
                          };
                    
                              console.log(time[index].title,'===>',time[index].body);
                              return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
                        }
                      }else if(h_curr-h_notif ===1){
                    
                           if(m_notif > 55){
                             const payload = {
                                             data: {
                                             title:time[index].title ,
                                             body:time[index].body,
                            }
                          };
                    
                              console.log(time[index].title,'===>',time[index].body);
                              return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
                            }
                      }
                    }
}

   });
}

  res.json({result: `messages sent successfully.`});
});
```

i am getting this error i can't understand why

```
Error: Process exited with code 16
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:275:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at process.exit (internal/process/per_thread.js:168:15)
    at Object.sendCrashResponse (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/logger.js:37:9)
    at process.<anonymous> (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:271:22)
    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)
```

Comment: Hello did you look at the answers returned by https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Process+exited+with+code+16. In addition you are returning a response before the asynchronous work is completed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Comment: @RenaudTarnec i know i have to use PROMISE but i am new to Javascript i don't how to implememt it in my code .

Comment: Have a look at the video contained in the page I mentioned in my comment, as well as the full series (i.e. 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase cloud function exits with code 16 what is error code 16 and where can I find more info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57149416/firebase-cloud-function-exits-with-code-16-what-is-error-code-16-and-where-can-i)